# Thai characters into UTF8 Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

I tried to put some thai sings into a utf8 (utf8_general_ci) mysql database. The data is from the facebook api. In the JSON it looks like *\u0e41\u0e15\u0e07\u0e08\u0e49* (original: แตแจ้) and in the database i got some *????* (question marks).

What is the best solution to save this characters into a database?

This is my database connection with mysqli:

```
$DB = new mysqli('localhost', 'XXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXX');
$DB->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'");
$DB->set_charset("UTF8");
```

Comment: If phpMyAdmin shows `???` it does not mean the data is saved in the wrong format in your DB. Try to output the saved data and check then.

Comment: ppowtac makes an important point. It could just mean that where you're outputting it (phpmyadmin, console) you don't have the correct character encoding set.

Comment: i use heidiSQL for the output. I created a test script for the output. there are still *???* in the output. The content-type is utf8 and the connection to the database also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i found the sulotion....

the table was set to **utf8_general_ci** but not the utf8_general_ci table column... it was **latin1**....

Comment: Also, you must use ```;charset=utf8``` on db connection. For example :

```$db = new PDO("mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=db_example;charset=utf8", "db_user", "password");

```

Answer (score 1):

in your db table, set your column collation to utf8_unicode_ci, then :

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I returned the charterset with the function $mysqli->character_set_name() it is "latin1".

Comment: There is a method for mysqli: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php. I used theme, but i have still ??? in the databse

Comment: try in your case $DB->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it also doesn't work...

I looked into the cantao script. They also use mysqli. thats the exactly connection start:

`$GLOBALS['TL_CONFIG']['dbCharset']   = 'UTF8';`
`@$this->resConnection->set_charset($GLOBALS['TL_CONFIG']['dbCharset']);`

Is this a problem from mysqli?

Comment: Ok, everything is utf8:

`Array
(
    [Variable_name] => character_set_client
    [Value] => utf8
)
Array
(
    [Variable_name] => character_set_connection
    [Value] => utf8
)
Array
(
    [Variable_name] => character_set_database
    [Value] => utf8
)
Array
(
    [Variable_name] => character_set_filesystem
    [Value] => binary
)
Array
(
    [Variable_name] => character_set_results
    [Value] => utf8
)
Array
(
    [Variable_name] => character_set_server
    [Value] => utf8
)
Array
(
    [Variable_name] => character_set_system
    [Value] => utf8
)` but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks Ben. I have set this 3 lines before insert Query and it worked.

Comment: worth noting: mysql_ was deprecated in php5 and removed in php7