# Facing Thai language display issue in AWS Glue ETL with MySQL target. How to fix?

Tags: mysql, pyspark, etl, aws-glue, thai

I'm using **AWS Glue ETL** and have chosen **MySQL** as the target. However, I'm encountering an issue with **Thai language** displaying as **'???'** when saving to MySQL. How can I resolve this problem?

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog( 

     database="test",

     table_name="test",

     transformation_ctx="test_node", 

     additional_options={"charset": "utf8"}

 )
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341095/thai-characters-into-utf8-database

Comment: You should be using character set `utf8mb4` with MySQL